# unexpected output while using list(and nested dictionary)

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-sdk

I am trying to work on some cloudformation template using the python libarary called troposhere.  Here is the general overview of how troposhere works if one does not know about it....you can skip this part to go to my question section, if you know how troposhere work....

And onto my question ...
Here is where all my trouble starts.  Here i have a funtion called get_data that does some text parsing...followed by a simple for loop that will create a list for me which has multiple dictionry in it called "mylist"...

Here is what i was expecting my output to look like, but as mentioned i only get one rule back

Comment: Why did you remove the code from your question?  It's no longer a good question.  I suggest rolling back your edit or deleting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop assigns a new list to `tsg.SecurityGroupIngress` for each iteration:

```
for i in mylist:
    tsg.SecurityGroupIngress = mksg(i['cidr'], i['proto'], [i['port']])
```

Change it to:

```
tsg.SecurityGroupIngress = []
for i in mylist:
    tsg.SecurityGroupIngress.extend(mksg(i['cidr'], i['proto'], [i['port']]))
```